# "URL Can't Be Used" error in adding facebook post with child_attachments via api

Tags: php, facebook

i'm `trying` to make a post on facebook using api with using child_attachments param, so i can pass multiple urls in 1 post.
In facebook debugger i'm passing json like that

```
{
  "message": "test debug",
  "child_attachments": [
    {
      "link": {
        "link": "https://google.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "link": {
        "link": "https://ft.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but i'm getting following error message

```
 { "error": {
    "message": "Invalid parameter",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "error_data": {
      "blame_field_specs": [
        [
          "child_attachments[0][link]"
        ]
      ]
    },
    "error_subcode": 2061006,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "URL Can't Be Used",
    "error_user_msg": "The URL you entered, \"https://google.com\" doesn't direct to a website. Please enter a valid URL and try again.",
    "fbtrace_id": "xxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

i've tried setting urls in app domains , i tried use urls with / without https and with/without www.

still no luck, can some one give me some advise?

Thanks,
Roman.

Answer (score 1):

ok, so i figured, the correct format should be like that:

```
{
  "message": "message to post",
  "link": "https://yahoo.com",
  "child_attachments": [
    {
      "link": "https://yahoo.com",
      "name": "name -1",
      "picture": "https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/ethereal_image_185195.jpg"
    },
    {
      "link": "https://google.com",
      "name": "name - 2 ",
      "picture": "https://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/ethereal_image_185195.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

note that even despite of the thing you adding links in the child_attachments, you must provide 'link' parameter also for post